# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.searchbox.client.config.HttpClientConfig.isRequestCompressionEnabled()Z

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am trying to use Jest Client for REST calls for elastic search. I am getting the following error in line `JestClient client = factory.getObject();`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.searchbox.client.config.HttpClientConfig.isRequestCompressionEnabled()Z
> at io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory.getObject(JestClientFactory.java:51)
> at JestTest.main(JestTest.java:22)

Following is the code:

```
    JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
    factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
                            .Builder("http://localhost:9200")
                            .multiThreaded(true)
                            .build());
    JestClient client = factory.getObject();
```

How can fix this error?